# Gerrit's "All side by side" doesn't open diffs in new tabs

Tags: firefox, gerrit

**Short version:**

On each Gerrit review there's an `Open All` button which used to open every diff in new tabs.

This behavior suddenly changed a week ago: now it opens a new window per file.
I haven't been able to understand why, although I googled this issue.

Do you know what can explain this change, and how I can get back to the previous behaviour?

---

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

1. Go to https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/82097/ with Firefox
2. Click on the `Open All` button
3. Notice it opens a lot of new windows rather than new tabs

---

**More practical details:**

- Our Gerrit setup hasn't change
- I observe this behavior with firefox (FF 27). The option `Tool > Options > Tabs > "Open in a new tab rather than a new windows"` is activated. (I don't know which version of firefox I had last week though)
- I have the same behavior with Internet Explorer 9
- I have yet another behavior with Chrome and Opera, but it doesn't work either (it only opens a new tab with the commit message. Other diffs aren't shown).
- I'm on Windows

Comment: (On Linux) I'm seeing the same problem with Firefox 27.0.1.  With 26.0, the diffs open in individual tabs as they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Firefox` try setting `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction=0` in the `about:config` menu. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I hope this config change won't have undesirable effects on other websites. However, there isn't any other proposed solution, and this one works. Thanks!

Comment: I've used this setting for a few months now, and I saw no undesirable effects.

See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction for details on impact on other websites.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that gerrit should not use the "features" parameter when opening a new window. This parameter restricts the behavior of opened windows (in particular they disable some ways to scroll the window: scrollbar and mousewheel), and I see no added value in this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Gerrit.  Using Chrome I was mystified at the meager results when I clicked any of the Diff buttons.  Thanks to this thread I tried Gerrit in Safari and I'm seeing the diff presentation I expect and can use.